# How to make Lord Shiva happy so he fullfills a wish?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam

This isn't a materialistic wish so please don't think I am trying to trade with Lord.

Comment: Try doing some sadhana of Lord Shiva. [This](https://m.youtube.com/@Adhyatmikta/videos) yt channel elaborates on some of them.Although nothing is guaranteed but if you are persistent and dedicated one day he would forced to acknowledge your devotion and come to help you!....Hope this helps!